# Какой шифр выбрать для уменьшения количества знаков после шифрования?

Tags: шифрование

Добрый день. Подскажите какой лучше выбрать шифр, который уменьшает количество знаков после шифрования. 
Например, нужно зашифровать текст "68464s8efsefdffs8484" - 20 символов. И чтобы на выходе (после шифрования) получился текст, который меньше 20 символов.
Надеюсь, сумел донести суть проблемы, как-то не особо разбираюсь в шифровках.

Comment: У каждого шифрования свой диапазон количества символов.

Comment: @Никола Кривошея, шифрование никогда не уменьшает количество символов, этим занимается архивирование


@Bastian, то же самое - все популярные методы шифрования кодируют каждый символ словарем, и на выходе получается ровно та же длина